# Resizeable grid columns

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, resize, wpf-controls

I have 4 panels arranged one column after another. Each panel is fixed except the 3rd one, which should be as big as possible.

I want to be able toggle the visibility of the 1st, 2nd, and 4th panels.

I tried using a grid and just toggling the different columns:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="ResizablePanels">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" Name="gridColTools"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" Name="gridColStamps"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" Name="gridColCanvas"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="256" Name="gridColPropertiesAndLayers"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
<Grid>
```

but this just hides the panels without actually repositioning and resizing the 3rd panel.

I also tried a wrappanel, but I couldnt get that to work because the 3rd panel's size is unknown.

How can I toggle the visibility of the columns and resize appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the Width of the hideable columns "Auto", and then set the widths (40, 100, 256) on the controls that are contained in each grid column.

Right now you are specifying that your columns will always take a certain size - if you set them to Auto, the third column (with width *) will soak up any space they provide when you hide them.

As @Blam noted, you will need to use Visibility.Collapsed for this to work properly - Hidden won't cut it here, since hidden controls still take up space.

Answer (score 1):

Must be 30 characters

Visibility.Collapsed;